# visual notification when sound is played while muted

Tags: windows, audio, mute

Is there a way to get a visual notification when a sound is played while the volume is set to "mute"?

I.e. whenever a certain program produces a sound, its task bar button should flash, or regions of the screen should blink, or some other visual notification should show.

Assume no background music is running, since that would cause constant visual notifications.

System is Windows XP.

---

Addendum

Example scenario:
Browser-based game in chrome. I want to get a visual cue whenever chrome beeps, even if the particular tab or window is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has options for deaf people.  ( see: http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/opsdeaf.aspx )

> "Sound options include turning on
>   SoundSentry so that you can get visual
>   warnings for system sounds"

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately it only works on "system sounds". I tested with Google Chrome, and the type of beep it makes is apparently not a system sound. Might be something website specific.